# how can I use the for loop in java to print out the word chicken in a triangle shape?

Tags: java

Implement the printTriangle method so that it prints a triangle out of the letters in parameter str. For example, if str is Chicken then your method should print the following

> C
>   Ch
>   Chi
>   Chic
>   Chick
>   Chicke
>   Chicken

Also What if I wanted it to go from the full word chicken to c and also a different one that starts with the last letter and builds up to the whole word?

```
public class Triangle {

    public void printTriangle(String str) {


        for (int x = 1; x < str.length(); x++){

        }

       for ( int y = 0 ; y <  ; y ++ ){
           System.out.print(str.substring(y))

            System.out.println( );

    }
this is what I have :(
    //should look like a triangle
```

Comment: Why the empty loop? And do you know that there is a version of `substring` with one parameter, and a version with two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
String str = "Chicken";
for(int y = 1; y <= str.length(); y++) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, y));
}
```

> C
>   Ch
>   Chi
>   Chic
>   Chick
>   Chicke
>   Chicken

And other combination:

```
String str = "Chicken";
for(int y = 0; y < str.length(); y++) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(y));
}
```

> Chicken
>   hicken
>   icken
>   cken
>   ken
>   en
>   n

```
String str = "Chicken";
for(int y = str.length() - 1; y >=  0 ; y--) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(y));
}
```

> n
>   en
>   ken
>   cken
>   icken
>   hicken
>   Chicken

Comment: What if I wanted it to go from the full word chicken to c and also a different one that starts with the last letter and builds up to the whole word?

Comment: I edited my answer. When you know how it look like, try do it yourself. Will make you a better programmer.

Comment: I'm really confused...how can I get it to be chicken and take the last letter instead of the first letter away I tried y-- but it didn't work....and for the backwards one how can I make the letter n be at the top but where it would usually be when it's in the word chicken I tried " " for space but that didn't work..I only understand how to do the first chicken triangle

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    public class Triangle {

        public void printTriangle(String input) {
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
                System.out.println(input.substring(0, i + 1));
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Triangle().printTriangle("Chicken");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some things for this but my best method was this:

```
    public static void printOutWordAsTriangle(String word) { //Supply a String as the word to print
    int currentLetter = 0; //The amount of letters which are printed per line. 0,1,2... (So it looks like a triangle)
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray(); //Split the string into a char Array
    while (currentLetter < letters.length) { //Print every line
        String toPrint = "";
        int i = 0;
        for (char c : letters) { //Print all characters needed for the word-part of the line
            if (i <= currentLetter) { // check if the character belongs to it
                toPrint = toPrint + String.valueOf(c);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(toPrint); // Print the line
        currentLetter++;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use this method. You just need to supply a String.
Example:

```
printOutWordAsTriangle("WeLoveChicken");
```

Note: This will only print out the word in one direction. To the second, I am confident that you can do it.

Comment: I actually did it much, much, much more complicated than the oguy who answered. This works as well but it is not as easy. Anyways. Glad you have it working now.

Comment: Please use the other methods. They are less ressource heavy and easier to understand than mine.

Comment: thanks for answering but what you did does look a lot more complicated

Comment: Exactly :) The other methods are better

Answer (score 0):

This Is what you are looking for. Ignoring syntax error in your code, the problem is you are doing substring of a string, so when you start with Chicken, and you are getting a substring of say... 0(the start) you are getting Chicken, at substring 1, you are getting hicken. You can do what you are trying to do using my following example.

```
public static void printTriangle(String str) {

    String temp = "";

    for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++){
        temp += str.charAt(x);
        System.out.println(temp);

    }
}
```