# Remove a number from a string

Tags: java, string, numbers

I have to print this in the console:

9 7 5 3 1

7 5 3 1

5 3 1

3 1

1

My current code is:

```
  String seq = "9 7 5 3 1";
  Scanner nums = new Scanner(seq);

  int count = 5;
  while (count > 1){

  int firstNum = nums.nextInt();
  int secNum = nums.nextInt();

     if(firstNum > secNum ){
        //I'm trying to remove the first number in each iteration of the sequence.
        seq = seq.remove(firstNum);
        count --;
        System.out.println(seq);
     }
 }
```

How would I remove the first number each time? I don't want to write a bunch of loops for each condition.

Comment: Do you have to start with a `String`? If so, `seq = seq.substring(2);` should work in the loop. Just keep printing `seq`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Only if the numbers stay below 10.

Comment: @Schred True. But it's a `String`. Which is why I asked the first question in my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I use the for loop in java to print out the word chicken in a triangle shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089334/how-can-i-use-the-for-loop-in-java-to-print-out-the-word-chicken-in-a-triangle-s)

Answer (score 2):

You should work with numbers, not strings.

```
int start = 9;
while (start >= 1) {
    int temp = start;
    while (temp > 0) {
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
        temp -= 2;
    }
    start -= 2;
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

In your code:

```
seq = seq.remove(firstNum);
```

String does not have a `remove` method that takes an `int`.

If you want to remove a number from the sequence, consider storing the numbers in a data structure like an `ArrayList` that has a [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method.

---

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(9, 7 ,5, 3, 1));
int n = list.size();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(list);
    list.remove(0);
}
```

**Note: Do not do this**

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

If your condition is on `list.size()` and you remove in the loop, then the list size is changed while iterating and the loop will run `n / 2` times only.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) to safely remove elements from a list.

Answer (score 1):

Change your if-statement to this:

```
if (firstNum > secNum ){ 
    count --;
    System.out.println(seq);

    // This means "Assign seq the value of everything after the next space (" ")
    seq = seq.substring(seq.indexOf(" ") + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Harshal Parekh said, you should use numbers. You can do this

```
for (int i = 9; i --> 1;) {
    for (int j = i; j --> 1;) System.out.print(j + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

You can also use recursion to avoid that extra space at the end of the line:

```
public void printLine(int from) {
  if (from == 1) {
    System.out.println(1);
    return;
  }
  System.out.print(from + " ");
  printLine(from - 2);
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
for (int i = 9; i --> 1;) printLine(i);
```

Or like this:

```
printLines(9);
//if you define this method, that is
public void printLines(int from) {
  printLine(from);
  printLines(from - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach :

```java
  //code to get input in string
  String seq = "9 7 5 3 1";
  while (seq.length() >1){
         int index= seq.indexOf(" ")>0? seq.indexOf(" ")+1: 0 ;
         seq = seq.substring(index);
         System.out.println(seq);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you use `nums.hasNextInt()` before `nums.nextInt()` to avoid `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
2. [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) does not have `remove` method. You can make use of [substring​(int beginIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to remove the part of the string before the index, `beginIndex`.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String seq = "9 7 5 3 1";
           Scanner nums = new Scanner(seq);

           int count = 5;
           while (count > 1 && nums.hasNextInt()) {
               int firstNum = nums.nextInt();
               int secNum = 0;
               if (nums.hasNextInt()) {
                   secNum = nums.nextInt();
               }
               if (firstNum > secNum) {
                   System.out.println(seq);
                   seq = seq.substring(seq.indexOf(' ', seq.indexOf(' ') + 1) + 1);
                   count--;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   9 7 5 3 1
   5 3 1
   1
   ```

   **Note:** `String` has two overloaded methods with the name, [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and the 
   solution uses both of them.